# How to pass JSON to Redux -> React Component

Tags: reactjs, express, redux

I am building an app from this boilerplate: https://github.com/werein/react

I am hitting an API that requires a Secret Key, so I am going to Fetch the JSON via Express (server.js) and pass it to my component as props.

How do I glue everything together to get the JSON in as props?

I tried just to pass some Dummy JSON

```
app.get('yourinfo', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ 'a': 'Some JSON' });
});

  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <Layout>
      <Match exactly pattern="/yourinfo" component={App} />
    </Layout>
  </ConnectedRouter>
```

And I don't get anything rendered in when I inspect this.props.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're mixing server side and client side code. You need to make a get request to `/yourinfo` with something like `fetch` from a react component or promise middleware then populate your store with the response

Comment: Read this section of the docs http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am stuck on populating the store. I am querying the api through express because I have to pass my secret key with every call. Do you mean query it via express, then do another get to query the contents after that and put into redux?

Comment: Yes you do need to make two requests. It starts on the client side with a fetch call to your servers endpoint.. your server then makes a call to the api, then your server sends that data back to initial fetch call on the client. Remember.. your React app is running on some random browser, whereas your server is running at a location of your choice. Because the code is running in completely separate places your need your server to act as a proxy to keep your api key a secret

Comment: Wow, thank you for the explanation. You explained it so clearly, it totally makes sense. You ever look back and wonder how you were stuck on something in the first place? Not sure how to give you the best answer, but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Remember when using redux that your application's state is stored in the redux state. And all changes to the state are done through actions which are dispatched.

So, to save your API key in your application's state, just create an action & dispatch it:

```
// the "save API key" action
export function saveAPIKey(key) {
  return {
    type: APP_APIKEY,
    key,
  };
}

// to use the loadAPIKey action, dispatch it
import store from './store/store';
import { saveAPIKey } from './path/to/actions';

fetch('/my/api/endpoint')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => store.dispatch(saveAPIKey(data.key)));
```

That's the basic idea, but there is a simpler way of doing it. If you read through [the redux docs on async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) you'll see that you can use the redux-thunk package to create an action that behaves asynchronously. It looks a little more complicated, but it has the advantage of putting all the code handling the asynchronous actions in one place, rather than spreading `fetch` calls throughout your code.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the response. I understand this concept, but the issue is I need to pass my secret key out for each api call. So I am trying to perform the request with server side code to keep a secret. The issue is how to pass the payload from express to redux.